# SEO optimization for multistore

Tags: indexing, seo

I am working on the SEO optimization of a multistore. For example I have in the same language and same currency website:

- www.test.com
- subdomain.test.com

Why like that? Because main is for wholesales customers and subdomain for retail customers.

We have too much products so it's impossible to make different text for shared products.

So we had to set the product for both stores. So the duplication is almost 100% (of course the menu and some information around product is a little bit different but the product is the same) For us and also for Google is main www.test.com.

What is the best in this case to get from google the best ratio? I'm wondering if our main website isn't a little bit go down cos of duplication on subdomain.

I was thinking about setting subdomain to noindex,nofollow and let Google index only main website.

Or if this isn't problem for Google I can let like now but I'm not sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: I didn´t know that this is question off-topic. Could you please help me and tell me where can I ask for such as question? It´s pretty hard to find right answer.

Comment: You use the tag, but yet refuse to read it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use canonical tag on the subdomain pages. Canonical Tag tells search engines that a specific URL represents the master copy of a page. Using the canonical tag prevents problems caused by identical or "duplicate" content appearing on multiple URLs. Following is the syntax of canonical tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.test.com"/>
```